# Type for delegate commands

Tags: typescript

I have two model types:

```
type ModelA = { type: 'ModelA' }
type ModelB = { type: 'ModelB' }
type Model = ModelA | ModelB
```

Now I have a delegate function `executeCommand`:

```
function executeCommand(model: Model, command)
```

Valid commands for `ModelA` are `read` and `update` and valid commands for `ModelB` are `add` and `delete`.

Now I want to create an generic type for `command` so I can restrict the `command`s passed to `executeCommand` function based on the type of `model`.

I don’t want to use interfaces or classes.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typing-functions?file=index.ts

```
type ModelA = { type: 'ModelA' }
type ModelB = { type: 'ModelB' }
type Model = ModelA | ModelB

type readCommand = (model: ModelA) => void;
type updateCommand = (model: ModelA) => void;

type addCommand = (model: ModelB) => void;
type deleteCommand = (model: ModelB) => void;


function executeCommand(model: ModelB, command: addCommand|deleteCommand): void;
function executeCommand(model: ModelA, command: readCommand|updateCommand): void;
function executeCommand<T=Model>(model: T, command: (model: T) => void): void {
  console.log(model, command);
  command(model);
}

const addCommandImplementation: addCommand = (model: ModelB) => {
  console.log('add command with',model);
}

const readCommandImplementation: readCommand = (model: ModelA) => {
  console.log('read command with',model);
}

const f: Model = {type: 'ModelA'};

executeCommand(f,addCommandImplementation);
executeCommand(f,readCommandImplementation);
```